# Ajax Post Request to PHP not working even after enabling CORS Error:405 Post method not available

Tags: post, cors

I am trying to send some data through a Ajax Post method to a PHP.To test it initially both the JS and PHP are in the same package. I have read that I need to enable cross domain operations from them to work and did as per the instructions. But still i receive this error from the console: POST http://localhost:8000/php/ajax-follow.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "↵… localhost:8000↵    ↵  ↵↵", status: 405, statusText: "Method Not Allowed"}

Code for Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $('#followbtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#followbtn').fadeOut(300);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'php/ajax-follow.php',
      type: 'post',

      data: {'action': 'follow', 'userid': '11239528343'},
      success: function(data, status) {
        if(data == "ok") {
          $('#followbtncontainer').html('<p><em>Following!</em></p>');
          var numfollowers = parseInt($('#followercnt').html()) + 1;
          $('#followercnt').html(numfollowers);
        }
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
  });
```

Code for ajax-follow.php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8000");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true ");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size,
    X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control");


if($_POST['action'] == "follow") {
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
fclose($file);


  echo "ok";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try and keep your method capitalized in the ajax call like so: `type: 'POST'`. It looks like you have stated as much under `Access-Control-Allow-Methods:` in your `ajax-follow.php`

Comment: I have tried 'POST' as well. but still it gives the same error 405 method not allowed